# How to make draw on picturebox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a drawing software using visual basic 2010. I only want to know how to add drawing effect to picture box in vb.net

Comment: What is a *drawing effect*, in your view? Did you see/test some of the examples you can find  in the MSDN documentation? I.e., do you have some code that's not working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim Graphics As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
'Use the Graphics variable to draw on the picture box.
```

Comment: This is exactly what you must not do. Most Controls raise a Paint event. You draw on a Control's surface using the Graphics object provided by `PaintEventArgs`.